# Using Static Method to Create Default Object?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm working on building a die rolling program for use in an XNA project I'm using, but my question here is purely c# and is more on best practices or any gotchas I might need to look out for. Is it an effective use of a static method in an object's definition to outline the creation of default items.

Below is the snapshot of the code I'm using,

```
public struct Die{
    private DieType die;
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static Die d2 = new Die(DieType.d2);
    public static Die d4 = new Die(DieType.d4);
    public static Die d6 = new Die(DieType.d6);
    public static Die d8 = new Die(DieType.d8);
    public static Die d10 = new Die(DieType.d10);
    public static Die d12 = new Die(DieType.d12);
    public static Die d20 = new Die(DieType.d20);
    public static Die d100 = new Die(DieType.d100);

    public Die(DieType die){
        this.die = die;
    }

    public int Roll(){
        return rnd.Next((int)die);
    }
}
```

Using this my code seems to compile without issues when I make references to the Die struct:

```
List <Roll> diceCup = new List<Roll>();
diceCup.Add (new Roll(4,Die.d6,-Die.d6.Roll()));
```

Roll is another struct that takes a Quantity of Die to roll and a short to modify it by.

In the case of my sample above, I create a new roll of 4d6-d6.

Is this going to cause me any problems later down the line if I am creating new instances of these dice?

Thanks for the advice!

Andrew

Comment: Few quick sidenotes: You have a `;;` on your second code block. Also, it's recommended that you use a single static Random object, instead of creating a new one every time. (If two Random objects are created at the same time, they will create the exact same numbers)

Comment: What is `(short)(-Die.d6().Roll())` doing? It's ugly.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva Thanks for the double semicolon, I'll get that cleaned up for sure. So you are suggesting that I take the random object out of the individual die and pass it instead as a parameter? That would put a limit on the number of objects that get created.

Comment: @Paul. The Die object has a method called Roll that will generate a random number between 1 and its given die size. In this case it will generate a random number between 1 and 6, invert it with the -, and then convert it to a short through typecasting for use in the Roll object. Probably not best to have an object and a method with the same name. :D

Comment: 1) Why limit to short? 2) What does the 3d argument to roll do?

Comment: Just switch `private Random rnd = new Random();` to `private static Random rnd = new Random();`

Comment: @Paul Roll takes three arguments, the first a quantity of dice to roll, the second the style of dice you want to roll, the third is a value you want to modify your result by. This is common for RP gamers. Seeing a roll string written out as 2d8+4. In the given example above, I'm rolling 4 6-sided dice, and subtracting from that total, the value of 1 6-sided die. As for why use a short? It uses less memory than an int, and I'm trying to minimize the memory footprint. I don't plan on passing it any 32-bit sized numbers.

Comment: @AndrewGoulart *Don't worry* about using an int here. You're not going to "waste memory" - I promise. If you *really* want to use shorts (btdt), then use them everywhere on the stack. Anyway, why not just write the original roll as Roll(2, 8, 4)?

Comment: The roll method should work fine as-is.

Comment: I just noticed that you're creating Die as a struct instead of a class.  If you have a small number of static objects that you reuse in a lot of method calls, the cost of passing them byval should outweigh the size benefit you get from using struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a static factory method to a lot of classes if I want to use them as a method group:

```
var people = names.Select(Person.Create);
```

In this case, I would just replace the set of different factory methods with a set of static properties and lazy singletons:

```
public class Die
{
    private static Die _d2;

    public static Die D2
    {
        get
        {
            if(_d2 == null)
                _d2 = new Die(DyeType.D2);

            return _d2;
        }
    }

    private static Die _d3 ...

}
```

I use these rather than just public static fields because I want to delay their creation until their first use.

That can be simplified with `Lazy<T>` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

```
public class Die
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Die> _d2 = new Lazy<Die>(() => new Die(DyeType.D2));
    private static readonly Lazy<Die> _d3 = new Lazy<Die>(() => new Die(DyeType.D3));
    private static readonly Lazy<Die> _d4 = new Lazy<Die>(() => new Die(DyeType.D4));

    public static Die D2 { get { return _d2.Value; } }
    public static Die D3 { get { return _d3.Value; } }
    public static Die D4 { get { return _d4.Value; } }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Patrick, maybe I'm not understanding, but I don't mind opening up my statics as public items in the object declaration because they won't ever be changing, and they are meant to be referenced as just that, a single instance of a particular sided die. I don't see the need for the extra encapsulation on something this simple. If they are static, they should never be changing.

Comment: While it isn't critical to only initialize your reference type statics the first time you need them, it has become my standard pattern.  It prevents unused statics from consuming memory or wasting the time required to initialize them.   It's not going to matter much in a small app or on tiny classes, but on larger objects that take have non-trivial initialization steps, there's a real cost to creating an object that's never used.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include my rationale for using properties over fields, and I added an example of using the Lazy class to clean up the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the introduction of Lazy. That definitely looks a lot cleaner than your initial example.